# Python3.7 not showing up during module load on linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, environment-modules

I've installed python3.7 on my school's computing cluster without using pip or sudo. I added the python path to `$PATH` variable in the bashrc. But it still doesnt show the module when I try to do `module spider python`. Am I missing any steps? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you have loaded your .bashrc? like `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a newly installed software through the `module` command, there should be a modulefile describing this software installation under an enabled modulepath.

Let's say `/usr/share/modulefiles` is a directory containing modulefiles. Create a `python` directory in this modulepath directory. Then create the `3.7` file in this directory:

```
#%Module
append-path PATH /the/path/to/your/python/3.7/installation
```

With this new file create in the modulepath directory, you have create a new modulefile: `python/3.7`.

Enable the modulepath directory:

```
$ module use /usr/share/modulefiles
```

Now you can see the `python/3.7` module:

```
$ module av python
--------- /usr/share/modulefiles ---------
python/3.7

$ module show python/3.7
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/share/modulefiles/python/3.7:

append-path     PATH /the/path/to/your/python/3.7/installation
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```